# Python/Pandas: Remove unwanted text in a column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, wildcard

I wish to remove some unwanted text in a column, here is an example of the dataframe:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                        'value': ['12646586.0125284002019-11-25W001382021-02-25FORWARD',
                                  '12646586.0125284002019-11-25W001382021-02-25FORWARD',
                                  '12646586.0125284002019-11-25W001382021-02-25FORWARD',
                                  '12646586.05116292020-01-28W001382021-02-25FORWARD',
                                  '12646586.05116292020-01-28W001382021-02-25FORWARD',
                                  '12646586.05116292020-01-28W001382021-02-25FORWARD']})
```

I want to remove the ".0" only in the column 'value', ideally it should be like this:

```
   Id                                              value
0   1  12646586125284002019-11-25W001382021-02-25FORWARD
1   2  12646586125284002019-11-25W001382021-02-25FORWARD
2   3  12646586125284002019-11-25W001382021-02-25FORWARD
3   4    126465865116292020-01-28W001382021-02-25FORWARD
4   5    126465865116292020-01-28W001382021-02-25FORWARD
5   6    126465865116292020-01-28W001382021-02-25FORWARD
```

Only the '.0' removed from the string in the column. I tried code like this:

```
df_test['value'] = df_test['value'].str.replace("\s.0", "")
```

It did not work, so please help if possible. Much appreciate it.

Comment: `df_test['value'].str.replace(r"\.0", "")`?

Comment: `df_test['value'].str.replace(r".0", "", regex=False)` should do the trick.

Comment: Ok, it seems you simply forgot to escape the dot in the regex, right?

Comment: ah yes, I forgot to inplace=True?

Comment: `df_test['value'] = df_test['value'].str.replace(r"\.0", "")`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, done! many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `\s.0` pattern matches a whitespace, then any char but a line break char, and a `0`.

You wanted to match a dot and a zero:

```py
df_test['value'] = df_test['value'].str.replace(r"\.0", "")
>>> df_test
   Id                                              value
0   1  12646586125284002019-11-25W001382021-02-25FORWARD
1   2  12646586125284002019-11-25W001382021-02-25FORWARD
2   3  12646586125284002019-11-25W001382021-02-25FORWARD
3   4    126465865116292020-01-28W001382021-02-25FORWARD
4   5    126465865116292020-01-28W001382021-02-25FORWARD
5   6    126465865116292020-01-28W001382021-02-25FORWARD
```